# GCP artifact registry logs not showing in Logs Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-logging, google-artifact-registry

I am attempting to get logs from Google Artifact Registry to show in Logs Explorer UI.  I have read and followed the docs for audit logging here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable

and steps for Artifact Registry in particular here:
https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/audit-logging

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I would see logs when pushing or pulling artifacts? Any Insight helps

I have enabled logs and don't have any filters applied in the Logs Explorer. Is there any other configuration or permissions I need to setup access logs. I have read and followed the docs for audit logging here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable

and steps for Artifact Registry in particular here:
https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/audit-logging

Comment: How long since enabling? There is a delay before logs are available.

Comment: As of posting this question it was about 1.5 hours since I enabled logging, made pushes and pulls but no luck.